# cannot create temp file for here-document: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

*Only other posts about this were 'no space left on device' or 'permission denied' issues.*

Trying to run something that uses puppeteer & chromium, which worked flawlessly for a while. Then I noticed something had ate up 40+ GB of storage on my Raspberry Pi (Ubuntu 22.04) and was able to track it down to the /tmp directory. I probably should have only removed files that were X days old but I cleared it all.

So now I'm getting this error;

```
/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:262
                reject(new Error([
                       ^

Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/snap/chromium/2427/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 369: cannot create temp file for here-document: No such file or directory
[0502/015204.839827:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(214)] Creating shared memory in /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.T68flj failed: No such file or directory (2)
[0502/015204.839841:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(214)] Creating shared memory in /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.57yYHj failed: No such file or directory (2)


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting

    at ChildProcess.onClose (/home/th/dsc/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:262:24)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)

Node.js v18.16.0
```

It's still able to save folders in /tmp so not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 1):

The two "missing directory" errors suggest you have deleted the application's working directories in `/tmp` and not yet restarted it:

> ```
> Creating […] in /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.T68flj failed: No such file or directory (2)
> Creating […] in /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.57yYHj failed: No such file or directory (2)
> ```

The permissions on `/tmp` itself should be `1777/rwxrwxrwt`, owned by `root:root`.

Comment: Just a simple system reboot solved the issue..

Comment: @rich, yes - you restarted the app